# Why this jQuery cookie doesn't get retrieved?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cookie

I have this code for two divs acting like radio buttons, they behave well but the the cookie I set does not get retrieved on page refresh.

```
var isboxed = $.cookie('boxed_cookie');
if (isboxed = 'isboxed'){
  $('.wrap').addClass("boxed");
} else {
  $('.wrap').removeClass("boxed");
}

var selectors = $('#sbox-boxed-layout div');
selectors.on('click', function(e){
  var $this = $(this);
  selectors.removeClass('selected').addClass('disabled');
  $this.addClass('selected').removeClass('disabled');

  if ($('#sbox-boxed-layout div.on').hasClass('selected')){
    $('.wrap').addClass("boxed");
    $.cookie('boxed_cookie', 'isboxed' , { expires: 7, path: '/' });
  } else {
    $('.wrap').removeClass("boxed");
    $.cookie('boxed_cookie', 'isfull' , { expires: 7, path: '/' });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`if (isboxed = 'isboxed'){` should use `==` (double-equals) for comparison.

Comment: Thanks I already changed this and it is not solving the issue

Comment: It looks like it is working on jsfiddle, no clue why it is not on my local since I have other jquery cookie set and all work fine.